# Can Microsoft Information Protection SDK work with GCC or GCCH cloud?

Tags: gcc, cloud

Can Microsoft Information Protection SDK work with GCC or GCCH cloud?

I registered a client application with Microsoft Azure Government cloud.
How to initialize MIP SDK in order to connect to GCC or GCCH cloud?
I need to use File API.

Regards,
Denys

Comment: Please avoid using acronyms without defining them. There is something called `gcc`

Answer (score 1):

I found out.
It's the same initializations both for Azure commercial cloud and GCCH.
But it needs TLS 1.2 enabled on client for GCCH.

Set value for Cloud property.

---

> var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("", authDelegate, "",
> "en-US") {
> Cloud = Cloud.US_GCC_High  };